# Simultaneously call the same function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 20 buttons on a page I want each button to call a timer that counts up from 0-10 minutes. I am using setInterval to call the function every minute and then adds one to the counter. This is working great if I only have one button but as I stated I have up to 20 buttons all needing to do the same thing. How can I get this to work?

```js
function countdown() {
  var counter = 0;
  var timer = setInterval(function() {
    counter++;
    $("#init").html(counter);
    if (counter >= 10) {
      clearInterval(timer)
      counter = 0;
    }
  }, 60000);
}

$(function() {
  $("#init").click(function() {
    countdown();
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
}

.main {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  width: 45%;
  left: 50%;
  border: 1px solid white;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 2%;
}

.table {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.box {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: white;
}

.button {
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Table One</h1>
    <div class="table">
      <div><button id="init" class="button" type="button">Start</button></div>
      <div><button class="button" type="button" id="timerstart">Start</button></div>
      <div><button class="button" type="button" id="timerstart">Start</button></div>
      <div><button class="button" type="button" id="timerstart">Start</button></div>
      <div><button class="button" type="button" id="timerstart">Start</button></div>
      <div><button class="button" type="button" id="timerstart">Start</button></div>
      <div><button class="button" type="button" id="timerstart">Start</button></div>
      <div><button class="button" type="button" id="timerstart">Start</button></div>
      <div><button class="button" type="button" id="timerstart">Start</button></div>
      <div><button class="button" type="button" id="timerstart">Start</button></div>
      <div><button class="button" type="button" id="timerstart">Start</button></div>
      <div><button class="button" type="button" id="timerstart">Start</button></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Table Two</h1>
    <div class="table">
      <div><button class="button" type="button" id="timerstart">Start</button></div>
      <div><button class="button" type="button" id="timerstart">Start</button></div>
      <div><button class="button" type="button" id="timerstart">Start</button></div>
      <div><button class="button" type="button" id="timerstart">Start</button></div>
      <div><button class="button" type="button" id="timerstart">Start</button></div>
      <div><button class="button" type="button" id="timerstart">Start</button></div>
      <div><button class="button" type="button" id="timerstart">Start</button></div>
      <div><button class="button" type="button" id="timerstart">Start</button></div>
      <div><button class="button" type="button" id="timerstart">Start</button></div>
      <div><button class="button" type="button" id="timerstart">Start</button></div>
      <div><button class="button" type="button" id="timerstart">Start</button></div>
      <div><button class="button" type="button" id="timerstart">Start</button></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: all of them having same id?

Comment: Make your buttons selectable through a pseudo css class or some kind of data attribute that you can use as a selector, and add the event handler for the click event to these objects. Also, make sure that you have your logic in place so you only have either 1 countdown, or x countdowns depending on how you wish to handle it (should all buttons just start the single countdown, or are they separate countdowns per button?)

Comment: All buttons will be seperate countdowns and will need to be independent of each other. Im not sure I follow 100% on how to set a pseudo css class to each button. I  will google it and see if it gives me any insight.

Comment: Well, I used my suggestions to answer it already, using a data-attribute instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a unique selector to find your buttons and add the click event to that one, for example:

```
  $("[data-countdown]").click(function( e ) {
    countdown( e.target );
  });
```

The selector to get the matching buttons is now tied to a data attribute, called data-countdown. Any html element that has this attribute, will activate a timer on itself. The event argument will contain the button that really got clicked, which is identified by `e.target`. You can use the button as an argument for the countdown function and slightly alter it to take the given argument as a target.

(I reduced the time it takes for the timer to run to full just to make sure that you don't have to wait a minute to see changes ;) )

```
function countdown( button ) {
  var timer = $(button).data('timer')
  if (timer) {
    // has a timer
    return;
  }
  var counter = 0;
  $(button).data('timer', setInterval(function() {
    counter++;
    $(button).html(counter);
    if (counter >= 10) {
      clearInterval( $(button).data('timer') )
      $(button).data('timer', null);
      counter = 0;
    }
  }, 60) );
}
```

Here, I am saving the timer as an attribute of a button, and removing it when it has run its course. This way you could restart the timer, and clicking the button twice won't start the countdown twice, it wasn't really defined in your question how it should exactly be handled

```js
function countdown( button ) {
  var timer = $(button).data('timer')
  if (timer) {
    // has a timer
    return;
  }
  var counter = 0;
  $(button).data('timer', setInterval(function() {
    counter++;
    $(button).html(counter);
    if (counter >= 10) {
      clearInterval( $(button).data('timer') )
      $(button).data('timer', null);
      counter = 0;
    }
  }, 60) );
}

$(function() {
  $("[data-countdown]").click(function(e) {
    countdown( e.target );
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
}

.main {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  width: 45%;
  left: 50%;
  border: 1px solid white;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 2%;
}

.table {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.box {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: white;
}

.button {
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Table One</h1>
    <div class="table">
      <div><button class="button" data-countdown type="button">Start</button></div>
      <div><button class="button" data-countdown type="button">Start</button></div>
      <div><button class="button" data-countdown type="button">Start</button></div>
      <div><button class="button" data-countdown type="button">Start</button></div>
      <div><button class="button" data-countdown type="button">Start</button></div>
      <div><button class="button" data-countdown type="button"Start</button></div>
      <div><button class="button" data-countdown type="button"Start</button></div>
      <div><button class="button" data-countdown type="button"Start</button></div>
      <div><button class="button" data-countdown type="button"Start</button></div>
      <div><button class="button" data-countdown type="button"Start</button></div>
      <div><button class="button" data-countdown type="button"Start</button></div>
      <div><button class="button" data-countdown type="button"Start</button></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Table Two</h1>
    <div class="table">
      <div><button class="button" data-countdown type="button"Start</button></div>
      <div><button class="button" data-countdown type="button"Start</button></div>
      <div><button class="button" data-countdown type="button"Start</button></div>
      <div><button class="button" data-countdown type="button"Start</button></div>
      <div><button class="button" data-countdown type="button"Start</button></div>
      <div><button class="button" data-countdown type="button"Start</button></div>
      <div><button class="button" data-countdown type="button"Start</button></div>
      <div><button class="button" data-countdown type="button"Start</button></div>
      <div><button class="button" data-countdown type="button"Start</button></div>
      <div><button class="button" data-countdown type="button"Start</button></div>
      <div><button class="button" data-countdown type="button"Start</button></div>
      <div><button class="button" data-countdown type="button"Start</button></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thats perfect! Thank you!

Comment: Attributes are strings only...think you want to do this using `data()`

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks, not using jquery that often :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't set the same id at more than one element.
2. Use on-click event to call your funtion.

`<button class="button" type="button" onclick="countdown()">Start</button>`

Comment: This will only change the `init` element counting down. Other than that, using an onclick event in html code is rather frowned upon. Using event propagation is really a better way to go

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want each button to display the interval instead of 'start';
Loop through all the buttons and create a separate interval for each.

```

```
function countdown(el) {
  var counter = 0;
  var timer = setInterval(function() {
    counter++;
    $(el).html(counter);
    if (counter >= 10) {
      clearInterval(timer)
      counter = 0;
    }
  }, 60000);
}

const buttons = $('button');
for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  countdown(buttons[i])
}
```